# Instance member 'uid' cannot be used on type

Tags: ios

Trying to setup a login but an error keeps coming up on the last line with the `user.Uid`. Learning to program so any advice would help thanks.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toSignUp" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? SignUpVC {
            if (self.UserUid != nil) {
                destination.userUid = User.uid
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you store values in the `User` class object. What are the properties defined there?

Comment: Conform to the naming convention and name variables and properties with a starting lowercase letter. It avoids those errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `uid` is an attribute that can only be accesed through an instance of the `User` class, so accessing it thought the class directly won’t work. If you have an instance of the User class (maybe a `user` object, note the lowercase “u”), you’ll be able to access its `uid` member.